# jquery datepicker как обновить календарь при добавлении задачи?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Я делаю приложение которое работает без перезагрузки, как реализовать задачу где при добавлении задачи закрашивался день на календаре так же без перезагрузки страницы (сейчас я дообавляю задачи и чтобы дата закрасилась нужно перезпгрузить страницу). Добавление задачи (как и все операции с бд реализовано с помощью ajax

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что значит "дата закрасилась", но что бы там ни было, если что-то изменилось, то Рефреш должен помочь:

refresh()

Redraw the date picker, after having made some external modifications.
This method does not accept any arguments.

Code examples:
Invoke the refresh method:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "refresh" );
```

Либо установка парамера уже после инициализации (на примере disabled):

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", { disabled: true } );
```

Comment: Имею ввиду что у меня при загрузки срабатывает beforeDateShow где закрашиваются даты на которых есть задачи. Я гуглил и пробывал refresh но почему то он не срабатывает, может я ни туда его вставляю (я пробывал просто на страницу с календарем в скрипт и на событие onclick на кнопку добавить задачу. Невыходит

Comment: date_show = dateShow()  || date.dateForDb(); 
      
      if(date_show){
       $(".datepicker").datepicker("refresh");
      }

Comment: четстно говоря решил почти методом тыка, перед refresh добавляю в массив даты на которые есть задачи из БД после чего все это запихнул в функцию получения задач из БД. все работает но не могу понять почему и как=)))

Comment: )))
Главное работает.
А что работает - то колупать не стоит )